# Когда garbage collector ненужен и вреден?

Tags: производительность, сборщик-мусора

Перечислите, пожалуйста, задачи (желательно поконкретнее), при которых влияние `garbage collector` на производительность программы критична и несовместима с оптимальной работой программы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

любая задача которой паузы критичны. К примеру,

- проигрывание видео (пользователю не сильно приятно, когда видео просто останавливается, потому что gc решил поработать)
- кардиостимулятор (подожди пользователь, пару ударов пропустим, у нас тут gc.:) )
- другие приборы жизнеобеспечения.
- автопилот
- сетевые real-time игры. Только прицелился, а тут "сделай паузу, скушай батончик".

Comment: Можно ещё добавить программы работающие с биржами. Там задержки очень критичны.

Comment: Есть ли какое-то API, позволяющее отложить сборку мусора до определенного момента?

Comment: Биржи как раз пишут на java и выигрывают те, кто понимает, что это бред и дописывают на с/с++ небольшой код и получают профит.

А вот если нужно ручками рулить GC - значит неверно выбрали язык.

Comment: @KoVadim а касается это либо каких алгоритмов, а не только задач?

Comment: > Есть ли какое-то API, позволяющее отложить сборку мусора до определенного момента

Есть ряд параметров виртуальной машины, позволяющих гибко настраивать механизм GC.